# Does WSO2 ESB support AMQP 1.0?

Tags: wso2, esb, amqp, qpid

The latest WSO2 ESB (4.8.1) has documentation for configuring AMQP with RabbitMQ, which does not support AMQP 1.0. Does this mean WSO2 can not use AMQP 1.0 over QPid for example ? I'm very confused on this, since QPid seems to be referenced often in the WSO2 docs. Perhaps just as a client ? I really need a yes/no answer as to WSO2 support for both send and receive over AMQP 1.0,including remote brokers. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it has built-in support (what, in my opinion, looks very strange)

There is a custom "WSO2 ESB Message Store and Message Processor implementation for RabbitMQ" - https://github.com/Chilcano/wso2esb-rabbitmq-message-store

It can be used to configure/implement AMPQ 1.0 support